# "ReferenceError: is not defined" accessing variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

How to make variable named - **val1090** definied in **validator.js** accessible from **runesMetadata.js** ?

Im using nativescript vuejs and thats are metadatas for raddataform if it matters in this case.

I got error `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: val1090 is not defined"
JS: found in
JS: ---> <Runes>
JS:        <NavigationEntry>`

**runesMetadata.js**

```
import validator from "./validator";

export default {
  mixins: validator,
  data () {
      return {
        makeRuneMetadata: {
          'isReadOnly': false,
          'commitMode': 'OnLostFocus',
          'validationMode': 'Immediate',
          'propertyAnnotations':
          [ 
            {
              'name': 'r_makeRuneSpell',
              'displayName': 'Make rune spell',
              'index': 0,
              'editor': 'Text',
            },
            {
              'name': 'r_mpAbove',
              'displayName': 'If MP above [%]',
              'index': 1,
              'editor': 'Number',
               val1090, // <--------------------------
            },


      }
  }
}
```

**validator.js**

```
const val1090 = {
    'validators': [
        {
            'name': 'RangeValidator',
            'params': {
                'minimum': 10,
                'maximum': 90,
                'errorMessage': 'Value must be between 10-90.',
            }
        },
    ]
  }

export default val1090
```

**EDITED BELOW **

so validator would contain more objects like this

```
onst val1090 = {

            'name': 'RangeValidator',
            'params': {
                'minimum': 10,
                'maximum': 90,
                'errorMessage': 'Value must be between 10-90.'
            }  

};

const val115 = {

    'name': 'RangeValidator',
    'params': {
      'minimum': 1,
      'maximum': 15,
      'errorMessage': 'Value must be between 1-15.'
    }  

};


export default{
    val1090,
    val115
}
```

and in my component i made

```
created() {
    console.dir(val1090);
  },
```

so it gives me

```
==== object dump start ====
JS: val1090: {
JS:   "name": "RangeValidator",
JS:   "params": {
JS:     "minimum": 10,
JS:     "maximum": 90,
JS:     "errorMessage": "Value must be between 10-90."
JS:   }
JS: }
JS: val115: {
JS:   "name": "RangeValidator",
JS:   "params": {
JS:     "minimum": 1,
JS:     "maximum": 15,
JS:     "errorMessage": "Value must be between 1-15."
JS:   }
JS: }
JS: ==== object dump end ====
```

how to get only what val1090 object contains? only this i want

```
{
JS:   "name": "RangeValidator",
JS:   "params": {
JS:     "minimum": 10,
JS:     "maximum": 90,
JS:     "errorMessage": "Value must be between 10-90."
JS:   }
JS: }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exported `val1090` as default, so when you call this

```
import validator from "./validator"
```

You declare a variable `validator` containing what's exported by default in the validator file. Meaning that `validator` is the variable containing

```
    {
     'validators': [
        {
            'name': 'RangeValidator',
            'params': {
                'minimum': 10,
                'maximum': 90,
                'errorMessage': 'Value must be between 10-90.',
           }
        },
    ]
  }
```

So you should use `validator` instead of `val1090` in your `runesMetadata.js`, or change your first line to

```
import val1090 from "./validator"
```

EDIT : If your validator has more objects, it works the same. The `export default` value will be contained in the variable you import it. so if you export this :

```
export default {
    val1090,
    val115
}
```

and import it like this :

```
import validator from "./validator"
```

You basically create a variable `variable` with this value :

```
validator = {
    val1090: val1090,
    val115: val115
}
```

And accessing the `val1090` value can be done like this :

```
validator.val1090
```

Comment: so validator would contain more objects

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account this usecase, but the principles behind it are the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Having just a property name in a object initializer, i.e. just `val1090` is new ES6+ "shorthand" for `val1090:val1090` see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) ... for that to work, there MUST be a variable declared called `val1090` ... which isn't the case in your code

e.g

```
var a = 'foo', b = 42, c = {};
var o = {a, b, c};
```

works, because a, b and c are declared variables

```
var a = 'foo', b = 42;
var o = {a, b, c};
```

fails, because `c` is not declared